# Android Maven Eclipse still can't import apklib

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2e

I have an Android Maven project I'm trying to get to work with Eclipse. I'm also using the Android Support v7 AppCompat library. In my pom.xml I'm importing both the apklib and the jar. I've tried updating to the 0.4.3-SNAPSHOT version of the m2e-android plugin, but I still get the error

```
 Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
dependency=[android.support:compatibility-v7-appcompat:apklib:18:compile] not found in workspace    pom.xml /Studio54   line 1  me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.markers.dependency.apklib
```

Here's my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.lhs.app
    Studio54
    0.0.7-SNAPSHOT
    apk
    Studio54

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ossSonatype</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <platform.version>4.3_r1</platform.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        <version>18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>18</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>18</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>volley</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.testflight</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>16</platform>
                </sdk>
                                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do you have the source tree for your dependent library checked out in your local workspace? Due to limitations with the ADT you still need to have this.

Comment: No, I don't. The library in question is the Android v7 AppCompat library (the one with the action bar). Would I want to use the version in the Android SDK itself, or if the source has been downloaded to my local Maven repository, should I use that?

Comment: The source appears to be mirrored on Github: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/v7/appcompat/

Comment: You will need to mavenise the project though so that m2e-android can detect it.

Comment: I need to check out and mavenize the project you linked, in addition to the compatibility library I mavenized from the SDK directory?

Comment: I've not tried it with the AppCompat library so YMMV

Comment: But you've done it with other Android Support Lib apklib dependencies?

Comment: Not yet worked on that but there is an open ticket: https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/82

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update your android sdk. And check the eclipse updates from Help->Check for Updates tab.